Does an expanding universe naturally induce a Lorentzian metric in local nonexpanding coordinates?
When we consider the expansion of our spatial universe in time the standard method is through a conformal transformation of the spacetime metric as:
$$g_{\mu\nu}\rightarrow a(\tau)^{2}g_{\mu\nu}$$
with a simultaneous change of coordinates $\eta=d\tau/a$ to conformal time ( in the comoving frame, Note that in a general frame $a$ is a function of time and space coordinates both).
This doesn't sit right with me, as any set of coordinates x^{\mu} is technically a coordinate chart and it makes sense also then to consider a DIRECT scaling of the spatial coordinate functions that is:
$$x^{\mu}\rightarrow X^{\mu}=ax^{\mu}$$
Which we can write as:
$$\left[\begin{array}{c}
X^{1}\\
X^{2}\\
X^{3}\\
X^{0}
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
a\\
 & a\\
 &  & a\\
 &  &  & 1
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
x^{1}\\
x^{2}\\
x^{3}\\
x^{0}
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c}
ax^{1}\\
ax^{2}\\
ax^{3}\\
x^{0}
\end{array}\right]$$
Here $X^{\mu}$ correspond to expanding coordinates while $x^{\mu}$ are nonexpanding coordinates. Now if we choose a coordinate coframe (i.e. basis 1-form) we obtain:
$$dX^{\mu}=adx^{\mu}+dax^{\mu}$$
But we don't have this extra term in any of the usual formulations, my question is ultimately why not? it seems to make a huge difference!
Formally, the transformed metric (contravariant) $\tilde{g}^{\alpha\beta}$ should appear as:
$$\tilde{g}^{\alpha\beta}=\frac{\partial X^{\alpha}}{\partial x^{\mu}}\frac{\partial X^{\beta}}{\partial x^{\nu}}g^{\mu\nu}=\left(a\delta_{\mu}^{\alpha}+\frac{\partial a}{\partial x^{\mu}}x^{\alpha}\right)\left(a\delta_{\nu}^{\beta}-\frac{\partial a}{\partial x^{\nu}}x^{\beta}\right)g^{\mu\nu}=a^{2}g^{\mu\nu}+a\left(\delta_{\mu}^{\alpha}\frac{\partial a}{dx^{\nu}}x^{\beta}-\frac{\partial a}{\partial x^{\mu}}x^{\alpha}\delta_{\nu}^{\beta}\right)g^{\alpha\beta}-\left(\frac{\partial a}{\partial x^{\mu}}\right)x^{\alpha}\left(\frac{\partial a}{\partial x^{\nu}}\right)x^{\beta}g^{\mu\nu}$$
(I'm not entirely sure if the sign should be negative, but it doesn't change the substance of my question).
Note that by the very nature of this coordinate transformation, we aren't changing indices such that $\alpha=\mu$ and $\beta=\nu$ will always hold. then we can rewrite this as:
$$\tilde{g}^{\alpha\beta}=a^{2}g^{\alpha\beta}-\left(\frac{\partial a}{\partial x^{\alpha}}\right)x^{\alpha}\left(\frac{\partial a}{\partial x^{\beta}}\right)x^{\beta}g^{\alpha\beta}$$
In a comoving frame we have that $\frac{\partial a}{\partial x^{\gamma}}=\delta_{\gamma}^{0}\frac{\partial a}{\partial x^{0}}$
and therefore:
$$\tilde{g}^{\alpha\beta}=a^{2}g^{\alpha\beta}-\left(\frac{\partial a}{\partial x^{0}}\right)x^{0}\left(\frac{\partial a}{\partial x^{0}}\right)x^{0}g^{00}\delta_{0}^{\alpha}\delta_{0}^{\beta}$$
We get the standard conformal transformation plus an extra term that appears involving the gradient of the scale factor.
This implies that, from the viewpoint of our nonexpanding coordinate frame, an expanding space adds a line field to the metric. Such scenario is explained by Gibbons and Hawking. The authors therein utilize an everywhere timelike line field to switch between Riemannian and Lorentzian (i.e. pseudo-riemannian) metrics. Note the linefield above is always timelike as the universe expands in time (in any frame of course).
So my question is: Is there something wrong with this? If not then it implies that if we start by describing an expanding universe with a Riemannian metric then we obtain a lorentzian metric in local nonexpanding coordinate frames. Which implies the expansion of the universe defines our arrow of time (as I interpret it anyway). Would love to hear some comments or answers to this (or how I messed up lol)
ADDENDUM: before someone mentions Sylvesters law of inertia, I hvea to point out that it diesnt apply here for the same reason it doesnt apply to gibbons and hawkings treatment.
ALSO:  This coordinate transformation is inherently nonlinear, So the above may need to be modified. However, to first order in the nonlinearity the above should be a reasonable approximation.

Sylvester's law of inertia says you can't change the metric signature by changing the coordinates, so it does apply here if that's what you're trying to do. If that isn't what you're trying to do, please clarify. As far as I can tell, Gibbons and Hawking just talk about spaces of signature -+++ whose boundary has signature +++, which is nothing esoteric - just take Minkowski space between two coordinate times, for instance.

@benrg  maybe read that part of their paper again. Yes theyre talking about lorentz cobordisms,  however the riemannian and pseudoriemannian metrics are both 4-metrics and they use an everywhere nondegenerate line field to relate them. Another equivalent way of saying this is that a riemannian manifold admits a lorentzian metric if it admits a trivial line bundle (if im remembering correctly)

@benrg  heres another paper saying the same thing https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970071

@benrg  heres a better paper with the same formula as g& H  i just found which might have some bearing on the question: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268492746_Lorentzian_metric_induced_from_a_background_Riemannian_metric

Have a look at null distance construction of Sormani & Vega. This seems to be along the lines of your question.

@benrg  I think the answer to your objection lies in the fact that a conformal transformation is NOT a coordinate transformation in the strict sense (i.e. local chart given by a local diffeomorphism). Nevertheless its something we observe to be happening to our universe. If it were then the Einstein equations would be unaffected by it which we know they are not (unaffected)

@A.V.S.  thanks will do. Really this question boils down to the jacobian not being what is used in texts but has a line field which swotches signature potentially

Conformal transformations aren't something we observe to happen in our universe. Different times are just different parts of the spacetime manifold. They're like latitudes on earth. Some latitudes are larger (the ones nearer the equator). That geometric structure is determined by physical laws, but those laws don't involve latitudes nearer the poles being rescaled and deposited nearer the equator. If you'd started with $g_{μν}=a(τ)^2 η_{μν}$ then I would understand, but $g_{μν} \to a(τ)^2 g_{μν}$ seems wrong.

Some indices are wrong in your expression for $\tilde{g}^{αβ}$: it should be $a^2 g^{αβ} + a (\cdots) g^{μν} + \cdots$ (or $a^2 δ_μ^α δ_ν^β g^{μν}$). All $-$ should be $+$, I think. "$α=μ$ and $β=ν$ will always hold" is incorrect. If you do this calculation correctly you'll get cross terms. The cross terms are the reason you don't see this coordinate system very often: it's awkward to work with.

@benrg  yeah i figured the negative sign was wrong, and we end up with cross twrms which is why I explicitly mentioned it in the question).  we just consider the expansion of the universe as a conformal transformation of three-space. To use your latitude analogy two different points sharing a latitude and following parallel paths from pole to pole can describe the distance between them as a conformal rescaling as they propagate.

What you are referring to its a known fact, which is that you can see a Lorentzian metric as a Riemannian metric with the addition of a causal structure given by an everywhere nonzero line field. The everywhere non-zero field is an orientation for light cones and makes the resulting Lorentzian metric time-orientable.
In fact, given a Riemannian metric and an everywhere non-zero line field you can always write a Lorentzian metric. Vice versa given a Lorentzian non-degenerate metric you can always diagonalize it with respect to a Riemannian one and get the non-zero line field as the “eigenvector” relative to the negative eigenvalue. See my answer here.
This however, as expressed in the comments has nothing to do with the transformation you are performing. There are indeed errors in your calculations. If you perform the coordinate change correctly, you can check that the signature of the resulting metric does not change.
I give a small example in 2D.
Initial coordinates are $\lbrace t,x \rbrace$, final coordinates are $\lbrace T,X \rbrace$.
The change of coordinates is $$T = t\\ X = a(t)x$$
Starting for simplicity with Minkowski metric the resulting metric after the change of coordinate is
$$g_{\mu\nu} = \begin{pmatrix} -1+\frac{\dot{a}^{2} x^{2}}{a^{2}} & -\frac{\dot{a} x}{a^{2}} 
\\
 -\frac{\dot{a} x}{a^{2}} & \frac{1}{a^{2}} 
  \end{pmatrix} \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \mathrm{det}(g_{\mu\nu}) = -\frac{1}{a^2} <0.$$
where the dot is derivative w.r.t. $T$. So the signature of the metric does not change.

Thank you. Really I was interested in expressing the line field in terms a natural structure, and the gradient of the scale factor seemed like a reasonable  choice.  And that made me wonder then how to incorporate it into an expanding spacetime metric

Regarding your linked answer, how can writing the line field in terms of the normalized gradient of the scale factor be configured with the the scale factor also in the metric. I suppose i was looking for a way to make it all fit nice together

Really I'm interested in how the EH action in lorentzian and riemannian signatures relate in terms of said line field

Not in a simple way. If you expand $\sqrt{g}R$ in terms of the Riemannian metric and the line field you'll get a Riemannian contribution plus terms that contains contractions of the line field and/or its derivatives with the Riemannian metric and/or its derivatives.

since im considering the line field as the gradient of the scale factor, when we write the einstein/jordan type frames im hoping for an interesting set of cancellations here, when both conformal expansion and line field are taken into account.

i suppose im a little confused still. exactly what coordinates are being used in textbooks to get a metric that transforms as $g \rightarrow a^2 g$ that isnt obvious at all. as they usually give the same change of coordinates that I did.
